# Adding Attribute in existing CoreData while using default method i.e persistentContainer

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I am adding new Attribute in existing CoreData and i am using default method i.e persistentContainer in app delegate file not persistentStorecordinator. so where to add these option:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

i already add version number in core_data modal. After  searching i found that both property is by default *true*. **Is true**?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [Requesting lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration?language=objc)

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, 
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
NSError *error = nil;
if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                       configuration:nil 
                                 URL:storeURL 
                             options:options error:&error]) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Unable to load persistent store: %@\n%@", 
             [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: @paticleman , these code is return in getter method of persistentStorecordinator but i am not using that i am using persistentContainer(getter).

Comment: You can create the `NSPersistentStoreDescription` and set it into the container's `container.persistentStoreDescriptions` before loading. Set `description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true` and 
`description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true`

Comment: where??   - (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"CubnTimeInOut"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    
    return _persistentContainer;
}

Comment: Seeing the code helps. If you don't specify an `NSPersistentStoreDescription`, the persistent container will create one by default. It's returned to you in the completion handler for `loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:`. The default value for the two `NSPersistentStoreDescription` properties in your original question is YES, so you should not need to set them explicitly. You can verify this in the completion handler with `NSAssert`s, if you so choose.

Comment: error in saving context saying **Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration**

Comment: It sounds like you have more changes than just adding an attribute. If a mapping model can not be inferred, you'll have to provide one.